# what is PATH in $_SERVER?

Tags: php

What is PATH defined in $_SERVER?

I didn't see PATH defined in PHP.net manual. It says PATH_TRANSLATED and PATH_INFO only.

I got following detail in print_r($_SERVER).

```
[PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: Looks like the same path that you would see in `printenv` from the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the value of the system's [`PATH` environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29), which is a list of folders that binary commands are looked for in. Running `echo $PATH` in the terminal should yield the same (or similar, if under a different user) value.

Comment: thanks echo $PATH is little bit diffent but i got the idea.  echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin

Comment: @Praveen yes that's because you're running it as a different user than PHP is likely running under and thus may have additional folders defined.